# How to trim leading zero in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How to trim leading zero in Hive, I search too much on google but I didn't get any correct thing which is useful for my problem.

If digit is "00000012300234" want result like "12300234"

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin my question was for HIVE not for SQL Server and what I mention in my answer is working for me.

Comment: I see, I have removed my close vote on the question, however your answer still has the problem that I brought up.

Comment: have you try my answer can you share what is error in your problem @DennisJaheruddin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing to do just cast the string in INT

```
SELECT CAST( "00000012300234"  AS INT);
```

it will return **12300234**

Comment: This is not a good response to the question as it was written, as this suddenly gives you a different datatype.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin my question headline is "How to trim leading zero in Hive" and it's not edited and tag was already for Hive

Comment: By datatype I mean int vs string.

Answer (score 8):

you can achieve it by using: `regexp_replace` [String Function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)

`regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)`

The following removes leading zeroes, but leaves one if necessary (i.e. it wouldn't just turn "0" to a blank string).

```
hive> SELECT regexp_replace( "00000012300234","^0+(?!$)","") ;
OK
12300234
Time taken: 0.156 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> SELECT regexp_replace( "000000","^0+(?!$)","") ;
OK
0
Time taken: 0.157 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> SELECT regexp_replace( "0","^0+(?!$)","") ;
OK
0
Time taken: 0.12 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

OR Using `CAST` - cast to int to string:

```
hive> SELECT CAST(CAST( "00000012300234"  AS INT) as string);
OK
12300234
Time taken: 0.115 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> SELECT CAST( "00000012300234"  AS INT);
OK
12300234
Time taken: 0.379 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CAST( "00000012300234"  AS INT)  FROM <your_table> ;

--above SQL works works. But in case the number goes above INT range, then you need to have "BIGNINT" instead of "INT". Else you will see NULLs :-)

SELECT CAST( "00000012300234"  AS BIGINT)  FROM <your_table>;